# How to keep a PictureBox within the bounds of the Form

Tags: picturebox, bounds

I'm a newbie...please be kind. I am new to coding and starting out by creating a very simple platform game.

So far all has gone well but I need to keep my Player within the bounds of the screen and struggling with the code.

Player.Left and Player.Top are working fine but I cannot figure out how to stop him flying off the right edge.

Here is my code

```
            if (Player.Left < 1 || Player.Left + Player.Width > ClientSize.Width - 2)
            {
                Player.Left = -Player.Left;
            }
                         

            if (Player.Top < 1 || Player.Top + Player.Height > ClientSize.Height - 2)
            {
                Player.Top = -Player.Top;
            }

            if (Player.Right > 1 || Player.Right + Player.Width > ClientSize.Width - 2)
            {
                Player.Right = -Player.Right;
            }
```

I keep getting the error on Player.Right *Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only*

I've searched everywhere and tried all sorts of different ways to code this but I cannot get it to work. Have I done something really stupid and obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
if (Player.Left > 1 || Player.Right + Player.Width < ClientSize.Width + 2)
                    Player.Left = +Player.Left;
```